# Concatenating text from multiple rows into a single text string using XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across this block of code that I'm using to concatenating elements from multiple rows into one row using `XML Path`. But the problem that I'm facing is that I want to break the line of the concatenated string using `<br>` to make them appear one on top of each other when it renders on the web browser. But it is not being able to identify the line break.

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
    PO.OrderDate,
    (SELECT CHAR(10) + PS.ProductName + '</br>'  
     FROM tbl_OrderInfo AS OI 
     INNER JOIN tblProductEntry_Stock AS PS ON PS.ProductCode = OI.ProductCode
     WHERE OI.GroupCode = PO.OrderCode  
     FOR XML PATH('')) AS ProductList,
    PO.TotalProductPrice + PO.DeliveryCharge AS TotalPrice,
    PO.TotalProductQuantity
FROM 
    tblProductOrder AS PO
WHERE 
    PO.ShopCID = @MerchantId 
    AND CONVERT(date, PO.OrderDate) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem: Does your result not have the '</br>' or is the '<br>' not correct as indicating a line break? I guess, it's more the second option of my question and in this case, it's not really a SQL issue.

Comment: neither works for '<br>' nor '</br>'.. I thought this was the issue but turns out it isnt

Comment: Again, this is no precise answer. Please make your problem more clear: Does only your DB management tool not show the line breaks within the output? Or are they really missing? Can you copy the output to Notepad++ as example and check whether there are linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` to introduce a new line in the resultset.

> char(13) is carriage return
> char(10) is line feed

```sql
 SELECT PO.OrderDate,( SELECT PS.ProductName + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  FROM tbl_OrderInfo as OI 
        INNER JOIN tblProductEntry_Stock as PS ON PS.ProductCode = OI.ProductCode
        WHERE OI.GroupCode=PO.OrderCode  FOR XML PATH('')
        ) as ProductList,PO.TotalProductPrice+PO.DeliveryCharge as TotalPrice,PO.TotalProductQuantity
        FROM tblProductOrder as PO
        WHERE PO.ShopCID=@MerchantId AND CONVERT(date,PO.OrderDate) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: I tried this but still its not working